# How to store laravel log file data into database(5.5)

Tags: php, laravel, monolog

I need to store the Laravel log into my database . Can you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to App/Exceptions/Handler.php and then write below code in report() function and define your model as an ErrorLog

```
        $data = [
            'id'      => $this->createUniversalUniqueIdentifier(),
            'file'    => $exception->getFile(),
            'line'    => $exception->getLine(),
            'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
            'trace'   => $exception->getTraceAsString(),
        ];

          $dataArr =['id'     => $data['id'],
             'file'           => $data['file'],
             'error_summary'  => 'Line '.$data['line'].' '.$data['message'],
             'log_trace'      => $data['trace']
             ];
        ErrorLog::create($dataArr);
```

Your Model file should be like that
ErrorLog.php
    protected $table      = 'logs';
    protected $fillable   = 
    ['id',
    'file',
   'error_summary',
   'log_trace'
   ];

Answer (score 1):

Laravel [supports](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/logging#creating-monolog-handler-channels) [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) for handling logs. Monolog supports many different handlers, including database handlers like the [MongoDB handler](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/src/Monolog/Handler/MongoDBHandler.php).

You can use the MongoDB handler by adding a new channel to the `channels` array in your `config/logging.php` file, e.g.:

```
'channels' => [
    'mongolog' => [
        'driver'  => 'monolog',
        'handler' => Monolog\Handler\MongoDBHandler::class,
        'with' => [
            'database' => 'mongo-database-name',
            'collection' => 'log-collection-name',
        ],
    ],
```

Then you can set your default log channel to `mongolog` in your `.env` file, e.g. `LOG_CHANNEL=mongolog`.

Comment: But this is only supported in laravel 5.6+